# Deploy to Geronimo with Ant

Tags: tomcat, ant, deployment, geronimo

I have Apache Geronimo installed with Tomcat. I am building a war file and whant to deploy it to Geronimo automatically with Ant script. A standart way to deploy to Geronimo is to use deployer.jar, am I right? And I saw that there are tasks available to deploy jars on standalone Tomcat. So what would be the right way? Or maybe there are ant tasks to deploy to Geronimo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I found the article, where the way of using Geronimo's deployer is described. Everybody can found it following the [link](http://qbeukes.blogspot.com/2009/09/deploying-to-geronimo-from-your.html).

2) The other way is to use Maven instead of Ant. Special plugin exists for deploying programms to Geronimo. If you whant to read more about the plugin follow the [link](http://geronimo.apache.org/maven/server/maven-plugins/geronimo-maven-plugin/usage/modules.html)